# display data from more than one table

Tags: cakephp

I am learning cakephp and doing an example.I have many tables in my database such as User,Post,Comment,Friend,Photo and each table has a foreign key user_id.Now I want to display user's photo,his/her friend's posts, comments on those posts,user's friends etc like any social networking site after successfull login.can any one please suggest me how to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, there is an excellent tutorial that will teach you how to do all of this in the CakePHP cookbook. Take a look and give it a try! http://book.cakephp.org/view/1528/Blog

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the Containable Behavior to pull back a nested object graph that will have all of those fields.

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable

You'll get back results like this (...pulled from the cakephp book)

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [Post] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [title] => First article
                [content] => aaa
                [created] => 2008-05-18 00:00:00
            )
        [Comment] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [post_id] => 1
                        [author] => Daniel
                        [email] => dan@example.com
                        [website] => http://example.com
                        [comment] => First comment
                        [created] => 2008-05-18 00:00:00
                    )
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 2
                        [post_id] => 1
                        [author] => Sam
                        [email] => sam@example.net
                        [website] => http://example.net
                        [comment] => Second comment
                        [created] => 2008-05-18 00:00:00
                    )
            )
        [Tag] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [name] => Awesome
                    )
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 2
                        [name] => Baking
                    )
            )
    )
```